# OmniAuth Facebook dos not return E-Mail in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

This question is already on SO but since the API and Gem version changed I wanted to ask again and hope to find an answer this way.

I am using Rails 5 + Devise + OmniAuth

```
oauth2 (1.4.0)
omniauth (1.6.1)
omniauth-facebook (4.0.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
```

I created the Facebook app and made it public.

My settings are the following:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, 'xxx', 'xxx', scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'
```

E-Mail should come by default, I tried it setting the scope and also not setting the scope. The result is the same.

Facebook returns:

```
"info":{"name":"xxx yyy","image":"http://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/xyz/picture"}
```

The Hash does not contain the E-Mail.

I tried to access other info fields:

```
scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name,first_name,last_name,gender'
```

All of them work. Except for the email.

Why?

Comment: Having the same issue, but no matter what I define in `info_fields`, I only get `name` and `image` in the info hash.

Comment: I found out that this only happens if you try to get the data from the same FB user who also created the FB App. I don't know why, but I created a new FB account and got the email from that new account without problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a test account

You need to use a [**Facebook Test User**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-users/). Because if you try to signup with the same account that created the app in Facebook Developer, emails is not returned.